# Group by with rollup does not change column name to TOTAL when using IFNULL or COALESCE

Tags: php, html, mysql

How do i replace column name 'product_name' to 'TOTAL' and other column name 'inv_date' to 'TOTAL'. Tried with as below but to no avail.

```html
$query = "SELECT IFNULL(pm.product_name,'TOTAL') product_name,IFNULL(pt.inv_date,'TOTAL') inv_date, SUM(pt.qty) as total_qty,(SUM(pt.amount)/SUM(pt.qty)) as avg_rate, SUM(pt.amount) as total_amount1,SUM(pt.tcs) as total_tcs, SUM(pt.total_amount) as total_amount_net,
am.acc_name,pgm.product_group,psgm.sub_product_group,pim.pre_insp_name, ptm.purch_type_name, pt.* FROM purch_tble pt LEFT JOIN product_master pm ON pm.product_id = pt.product_id LEFT JOIN acc_master am ON am.acc_id = pt.acc_id LEFT JOIN purch_type_master
ptm ON ptm.purch_type_id = pt.purch_type_id LEFT JOIN prod_group_master pgm ON pgm.prod_group_id = pm.prod_group_id LEFT JOIN prod_sub_group_master psgm ON psgm.prod_sub_group_id = pm.prod_sub_group_id LEFT JOIN pre_insp_master pim ON pim.pre_insp_id
= pt.pre_insp_id $where GROUP BY pt.product_id, DATE_FORMAT(pt.inv_date,'%Y-%m') WITH ROLLUP"; $retval = mysql_query($query); $num_row = mysql_num_rows($retval); echo mysql_error(); if($num_row >= 1){ while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{ echo "
<tr>"; echo "
  <td>" . date('m-Y',strtotime($row['inv_date']))."</td>"; echo "
  <td>" . $row['product_name']."</td>"; echo "
  <td>" . round($row['total_qty'])."</td>"; echo "
  <td>" . round($row['avg_rate'],2)."</td>"; echo "
  <td>" . round($row['total_tcs'])."</td>"; echo "
  <td>" . round($row['total_amount1'])."</td>"; echo "
  <td>" . round($row['total_amount_net'])."</td>"; echo "</tr>"; } // while loop finishes } // if statement finishes
```

I also tried with following but to no avail.

```html
COALESCE(pm.product_name,'TOTAL') product_name,
COALESCE(pt.inv_date,'TOTAL') inv_date,
```

LASTLY, I also tried with following but to no avail.

```html
IF(GROUPING(pm.product_name),'TOTAL',pm.product_name) product_name,
IF(GROUPING(pt.inv_date),'TOTAL',pt.inv_date) inv_date,
```

The picture is self explanatory.
[image]

I am stuck don't where am I going wrong.

Hope I have been able to express question clearly.

Comment: If the value from the database is null, then `$varaible == null` will work. If it doesn't work, then the variable most likely don't contain what you expect. Do a `var_dump($row);` and check what that value actually is. I'm also assuming that `inv_date` is in the table `purch_tble` since you haven't defined it specifically in the select but have a `pt.*`?

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Comment: Why not just do the summary in php?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have re formated my question. If this can be resolved please.